# Why is my DataContext getting switched out from under me for a binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to use the `PropertyGrid` component from [PropertyTools](https://github.com/PropertyTools/PropertyTools) to display information on an object.  I can bind the object easily enough -- it's a property on my DataContext -- but one of the things that can't be derived from the object is the name that should be displayed in the tab header.  (And I can't change that; the object I'm inspecting comes from a third party.)  The proper name is a different property on my DataContext.

`PropertyGrid` has a way to change the way the tab header is displayed, by passing a `DataTemplate` to its `TabHeaderTemplate` property.  But something bizarre happens inside of the template: my DataContext is gone, replaced by something else.  When I try to say `{Binding TabName}` in the appropriate place inside the context, it errors out and tells me that `TabName` is not a valid property on class `Tab`.  But my `DataContext` class isn't called `Tab`; that's something inside of PropertyTools's codebase!

I'm still new to WPF, so I have no clue what's going on here.  Why is the in-scope DataContext that's perfectly valid in the rest of the XAML file being yoinked out from under me inside this template, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Posting the XAML as requested.  The template is literally just the simplest possible thing:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And then further down the page,

```
    <props:PropertyGrid
        SelectedObject="{Binding Value}"
        TabHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}" />
```

But for some bizarre reason, in the template it's trying to interpret the binding inside the wrong DataContext!

Comment: Tough to say without seeing a bit of XAML.  Try editing your question to include it

Comment: Also, in templates -- particularly inside grids, its quite common to be defining something that's not part of the visual/logical tree.  In this case, you don't get access to the DataContext because you have not inherited it.  All the more reason to post a bit of XAML in question

Comment: @Joe Added the XAML, for whatever it's worth.  I'm literally doing the simplest possible thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, just be sure to specify the source in your binding.  There are a few ways to do this.  One is to use the `RelativeSource` property of the Binding.  Another is to use `ElementName`

Give your UserControl this attribute:

```
x:Name="Root".
```

Then change your binding to use it

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.TabName}" />
```

Or use this:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TabName}"/>
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!  But... why was that even necessary?  I already have a data context; why is it switching the data context out from under me?

Comment: I freely admit, I simply do not know  There is a whole lot of Voodoo going on to make WPF work.   You will be defining visual elements and you'll think they should just have the DataContext of the thing that appears above them in the XAML and they don't.  Usually the technical reason is: "They are not part of the logical tree" and you just have to work around it.   You'll see it most of in Grids and with Menus.  It's why the many ways of specifying the Binding source were created, I guess.  In dire cases you might even have to resort to a "BindingProxy" (search SO to see what I mean)

Comment: Try using the "Live Visual Tree" in Visual Studio.  It's very helpful.  When you turn it on, you can select an element in the UI of your app, and have it be selected simultaneously i the tree in Visual Studio.  Then you can just right click on the element in Visual Studio, choose "Properties" and see everything about that element, including the current DataContext

Comment: One final thing:  If the TabControl is of the type that specifies its Tabs with an ItemsSource property and you are using that property, then I would expect each particular TabItem to have the dataContext of one item in the ItemsSource, not of the parent control.